# Deal with a large number of outgoing TCP connections in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm building a service that periodically connects to a large number of devices (thousands) via TCP sockets. These connections are all established at the same time, a couple of api commands are sent through each, then the sockets are closed. All devices are in the same subnet.

The trouble starts after about 1000 devices. New connections are not established. After waiting for a couple of minutes, everything is back to normal. My first guess was that the maximum number of socket connections had been reached and after reading through many similar questions and tutorials, I modified some kernel networking parameters like various cache sizes, max number of open files, `tcp_tw_reuse`, `somaxconn`. Unfortunately, it had little to no effect.

The problem does not seem to be burst-related: The first time I run the script, it works fine, but when I start it again a couple of minutes later, then I start seeing these errors. My best guess was that the number of open sockets builds up over time, possibly in the `TIME_WAIT` state. On the other hand, setting the `tcp_tw_reuse` parameter (which seems perfect for this scenario) did not have any noticeable effect. I close the sockets via pythons socket.close().

It may be important to stress that this question is not about a high-load server, but a high-load client! The connections are outgoing. I saw many server-related questions that were answered with the solutions I described above.

Comment: When you say *'periodically connects'* to a large number of devices, can you be more specific about how that works? Are these very short lived TCP connections and you're making them all every 5 minutes (say)? If so, could you spread these over the 5 minute period? 1000's of outbound connections in a 5 minute period should not be difficult. 1000's of connections all attempting to connect within a single second I can see might be more difficult.

Comment: These are very short lived connections. I would like to make the connections as often as possible, so it's not just about getting my couple thousand of connections work, but to do it as fast as possible. There must be a way to solve this problem by tuning some parameters somewhere, if a server can serve over a hundred thousand clients then it must also go the other way...

Comment: What is the error you are getting when connection "is not established"?

Comment: look here for a more detailed explanation on what you have to do to cope with large number of outgoing connections http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html

Comment: You might be hitting max number of file descriptors limit. Check for that `man ulimit`. TCP Timewait problem is unlikely as it's a client socket and is likely to use a new port number, so you should be okay.

Comment: The link @JD_GRINDER posted is useful. My summary would be for *client* exhaustion, use `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` to minimise sockets in `TIME_WAIT` state, but you also need to ensure they are not in linger state (unsent data on close). One route there (I think) is to call `shutdown (..., O_RDWR)` before you do the close. What we really need is the output of `netstat -an` showing these connections when things are busy. Are they stuck in `TIME_WAIT` or what?

Comment: thanks everyone for the comments!
@NikolaiNFetissov: I will check this tomorrow. 
@JD_GRINDER: I've been through this one :/'
@gabhijit: I set it to 100k, thats what I meant by "max number of open files"
@abligh: I actually tried doing a proper `socket.shutdown(...)`after using the sockets, but it turns out the host closes the connection automatically after sending the api reply, so shutdown results in an error, something like 'connection not open'

Comment: The connection errors are timeouts. I allow the socket 5 seconds for a connect.

Comment: Hi James I've been dealing with this kind of issue ever since and actually all you need to do is increase the ulimit. Both soft and hard!!